# Visual Studio Arquivo da solução .SLN nao comita

Tags: bitbucket

Estou tentando comitar o arquivo .SLN junto com o resto do projeto e ele não comita.

Não estou ignorando ele no ignore.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já adicionou ele?

Comment: Ja!!!!
Ele está nos INCLUDED CHANGES mas nao comita ...

Comment: E o que você quer dizer com "não commita"? Ele não saí da lista de modificações?

Comment: Nao nao sai... fica em INCLUDED CHANGES